# view-based table crashes xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nstableview

I have a problem with NSTableView. I cannot switch it to view-based table, because this leads xcode to crash. I create a new application with xcode, then I add a table-view to the main app window, then in attributes inspector I switch Content-Mode from Cell-based to View-based. After some time (about 10-20 seconds) XCode crashes. Also if I try to click Editor/Simulate document before xcode crash, I get Cocoa Simulator crash. So what's the problem with view-based table I how can I get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special you need to do with Xcode for view based NSTableView to work. The only thing I can think of is that something went wrong during install of Xcode. Try remove and re-install to see if that solves your problems.